# Web2Py Scheduler crashing the Postgress DB

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I am using scheduler as a Linux Service.

I created a file /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Web2Py scheduler service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -K myApp
Type=simple
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then install the service calling:

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched.service 

systemctl start /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched
```

Now after running for a day I see the Postgress DB is crashing or the apache server is crashing. I was not able to trace the apache logs. But in Postgress Logs, I found:

```
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [22303-1] spm@mydb LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [18799-7] LOG:  server process (PID 22304) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [18799-8] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT "scheduler_task"."id", "scheduler_task"."application_name", "scheduler_task"."task_name", "scheduler_task"."group_name", "scheduler_task"."status", "scheduler_task"."function_name", "scheduler_task"."uuid", "scheduler_task"."args", "scheduler_task"."vars", "scheduler_task"."enabled", "scheduler_task"."start_time", "scheduler_task"."next_run_time", "scheduler_task"."stop_time", "scheduler_task"."repeats", "scheduler_task"."retry_failed", "scheduler_task"."period", "scheduler_task"."prevent_drift", "scheduler_task"."cronline", "scheduler_task"."timeout", "scheduler_task"."sync_output", "scheduler_task"."times_run", "scheduler_task"."times_failed", "scheduler_task"."last_run_time", "scheduler_task"."assigned_worker_name" FROM "scheduler_task" WHERE (("scheduler_task"."assigned_worker_name" = 'myApp#22265') AND ("scheduler_task"."status" = 'ASSIGNED')) ORDER BY "scheduler_task"."next_run_time" LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [18799-9] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [22256-2] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [22256-3] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [22256-4] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [18799-10] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [22457-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-10-10 06:55:04 PDT
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22457-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22457-3] LOG:  redo starts at 0/C1C85F94
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22457-4] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/C1C88100
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22457-5] LOG:  redo done at 0/C1C880DC
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22457-6] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2018-10-10 06:56:16.925482-07
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22457-7] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [18799-11] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT [22491-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2018-10-10 06:56:31 PDT [22500-1] spm@mydb LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2018-10-10 06:56:31 PDT [22501-1] spm@mydb LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2018-10-10 06:56:31 PDT [22594-1] spm@mydb LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2018-10-10 06:56:31 PDT [22595-1] spm@mydb LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2018-10-10 06:56:33 PDT [18799-12] LOG:  autovacuum launcher process (PID 22491) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2018-10-10 06:56:33 PDT [18799-13] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2018-10-10 06:56:33 PDT [18799-14] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2018-10-10 06:56:33 PDT [22638-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-10-10 06:56:18 PDT
2018-10-10 06:56:33 PDT [18799-15] LOG:  startup process (PID 22638) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2018-10-10 06:56:33 PDT [18799-16] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

I have made sure the all the transaction are committed. But is it like the code is exiting at some point before the commit is called.

In the above logs:

```
2018-10-10 06:56:17 PDT [18799-8] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT "scheduler_task"."id", "scheduler_task"."application_name", "scheduler_task"."task_name", "scheduler_task"."group_name", "scheduler_task"."status", "scheduler_task"."function_name", "scheduler_task"."uuid", "scheduler_task"."args", "scheduler_task"."vars", "scheduler_task"."enabled", "scheduler_task"."start_time", "scheduler_task"."next_run_time", "scheduler_task"."stop_time", "scheduler_task"."repeats", "scheduler_task"."retry_failed", "scheduler_task"."period", "scheduler_task"."prevent_drift", "scheduler_task"."cronline", "scheduler_task"."timeout", "scheduler_task"."sync_output", "scheduler_task"."times_run", "scheduler_task"."times_failed", "scheduler_task"."last_run_time", "scheduler_task"."assigned_worker_name" FROM "scheduler_task" WHERE (("scheduler_task"."assigned_worker_name" = 'myApp#22265') AND ("scheduler_task"."status" = 'ASSIGNED')) ORDER BY "scheduler_task"."next_run_time" LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

Version

```
2.15.4-stable+timestamp.2017.09.02.04.02.22
(Running on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Python 2.7.12)
```

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 0):

First try to update web2py to the current version ([2.17.2-stable+timestamp.2018.10.06.18.54.02](http://web2py.com/init/default/download)). There was a problem in the previous version starting the workers.

Updating solves the scheduler problem in my case. If this doesn't solve the problem, please let me know. Maybe I have further advice.

Best regards
Clemens

Comment: I did an update and changed apache to ngnix. And i see the problem is happening at ngnix also.
2.17.2-stable+timestamp.2018.10.06.18.54.02
(Running on nginx/1.10.3, Python 2.7.12)

web2py is up to date

Comment: Is your app really called 'myApp' as you configured by the service start `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -K myApp`? Your have to specify your application by name. 'myapp' is just a placeholder. Best regards Clemens